# number of get requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to log how many get requests a user performed per day in asp.net mvc (3) after being forms authenticated. I suppose I could implement a ActionFilter or something but then I have to mark each relevant action/controller. Could I somehow intercept this globally? Thanks!

Christian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **global action filter** perhaps?

**Global.asax.cs**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    // Register global filter
    GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new AuthenticatedHttpGetTracker());

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

**Action Filter**:

```
public class AuthenticatedHttpGetTracker: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        // your logic to check if this request is an authenticated GET
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

However, i dare say there could be a tool which tracks this for you at the server level, rather than code level.

Worth a google.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look into this.